# How to render multiple HTML content in React Native without using Webview?

Tags: html, react-native, webview, react-native-flatlist

I am doing react native project.

There we are getting questions and answers as Json data. For Answers, We are getting HTML content in answers key.

So, I have to show number of answers in flatlist. 
Is there anyway to render HTML content without using Webview?

Json is like following sample:

```
 [ { question: 'How do I change or reset my password?',
       answer: <p style="color:#B22222">Color text and <span style="color:limegreen;">another color</span>, and now back to the same. Oh, and here's a <span style="background-color:PaleGreen;">different background color</span> just in case you need it!</p>
    }, 
    { question: 'How do I change my user name?',
       answer: <p>Here's a blockquote:</p>
<blockquote>Contents should not be swallowed. This is due to the enormous amount of harmful chemicals that has gone into this burger.</blockquote>
<p>That was a blockquote.</p>
    }, 
    { question: 'How do I change my email ID?',
       answer:<p style="font-size:18pt">Text size using points.</p><p style="font-size:18px">Text size using pixels.</p><p style="font-size:larger">Text size using relative sizes.</p>
    }, 
    ....
    ]
```

The data is dynamic and different answers & questions.

Any suggestions, Without using Webview, Can we render HTML content into flatlist for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [react-native-render-html](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html):

```
...
import HTML from 'react-native-render-html';

...

  <HTML tagsStyles={{
        p: styles.textAuthor}} 
        html={htmldata} 
        imagesMaxWidth={screen.screenWidth} 
  />
```

With this library you can manipulate HTML nodes before rendering.

Comment: But, That library also uses webview only. I have multiple HTML content.